# Makefile oneline for compilation of multiple source file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
SOURCE       = aaa.c bbb.c ggg.c fff.c

OBJECT        = $(SOURCE:.c=.o)

EXECUTION:
        gcc -c aaa.c -o aaa.o
        gcc -c bbb.c -o bbb.o
        gcc -c ggg.c -o ggg.o
        gcc -c fff.c -o fff.o
```

Is it possible to have a one liner in EXECUTION lable that creates object file for all source file rather that writing compilation for each source file

Answer (score 0):

GNU make knows how to compile C source files. So:

```
SOURCE := aaa.c bbb.c ggg.c fff.c
OBJECT := $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJECT)
```

Already does what you want. If you want to fully control the compilation command you can use a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
%.o: %.c
    <the compilation command>
```

This explains make how to create a `foo.o` object file from a `foo.c` C source file, if needed, by passing your `<the compilation command>` to the shell. It replaces the *implicit rule* that make knows already.

Of course, in the command you must refer to the involved files. You do this with the [make automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables): `$@` for the target (the object file) and `$<` for the first (and only) prerequisite (the C source file). Before passing the command to the shell make replaces them with the corresponding file names.

In your case you could thus use the following Makefile:

```
SOURCE := aaa.c bbb.c ggg.c fff.c
OBJECT := $(SOURCE:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJECT)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Note that make has many other automatic variables and also many [other variables of interest](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables), especially for C compilation (`CC`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, `LDLIBS`...). These variables are used by the implicit rules make already knows. The implicit rule make uses for C compilation, for instance, is:

```
$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

So, if you want to change the default for C compilation you can also play with these variables, instead of adding your own pattern rules.:

```
SOURCE := aaa.c bbb.c ggg.c fff.c
OBJECT := $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
CC     := gcc
CFLAGS += -DSOME_MACRO

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJECT)
```

The [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is very well written. If you want to know more about GNU make, it is the right place to visit.

Comment: if i want to pass some macro -DSOME_MACRO during compilation

Comment: Almost: `gcc -DSOME_MACRO -c $< -o $@`

Comment: one question who will trigger %.o somebody  has to invoke it right ?

Comment: Thanks a ton :)  , by mistake i deleted my comment

Comment: Yes, this is why I added an `all` target that depends on all the object files. If you type `make all`, make will build all the object files that need to be (because they don't exist yet or are older than their source file). And if you type `make foo.o` make will build only `foo.o` (if needed). And as `all` is the first explicit (non pattern) target in the Makefile, if you just type `make`, it is the same as `make all`.

Comment: Note that I also declared `all` as phony with the special `.PHONY: all` construct. This is just a way to tell make that `all` is not a real file that a recipe creates. It is more like a shorthand for all the object files. If, by accident, such a file exists make will ignore it and build the object files anyway.

Comment: Note also that `make -j4 all` will build all the object files in parallel. Nice if you have 4 or more CPUs. Kinda the whole point of _make_ really.